# SwiftUI - Button with Image is clickable outside

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a ScrollView with multiple Buttons. A Button contains a Image and a Text underneath.

As the images are pretty large I am using .scaledToFill and .clipped. And it seems that the 'clipped' part of the image is still clickable even if it's not shown.

In the video you see I am clicking on button 1 but button 2 is triggered.

[image: Gif showing the error]

This is my Coding. The Image is inside the View *Card*.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var useWebImage = false
    @State var isSheetShowing = false
    @State var selectedIndex = 0

    private let images = [
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1478368499690-1316c519df07?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2706&q=80",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507154258-c81e5cca5931?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2600&q=80",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513310719763-d43889d6fc95?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2734&q=80",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1585766765962-28aa4c7d719c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2734&q=80",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485970671356-ff9156bd4a98?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2734&q=80",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1585607666104-4d5b201d6d8c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2700&q=80",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577702066866-6c8897d06443?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2177&q=80",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513809491260-0e192158ae44?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2736&q=80",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1582092723055-ad941d1db0d4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2700&q=80",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1478264635837-66efba4b74ba?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjF9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2682&q=80"
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 40) {

                    Text(useWebImage ? "WebImage is used." : "SwiftUI Image is used")
                        .font(.system(size: 18))
                        .bold()
                        .kerning(0.5)
                        .padding(.top, 20)

                    Toggle(isOn: $useWebImage) {
                        Text("Use WebImage")
                            .font(.system(size: 18))
                            .bold()
                            .kerning(0.5)
                            .padding(.top, 20)
                    }

                    ForEach(0..<images.count) { index in
                        Button(action: {
                            self.selectedIndex = index
                            self.isSheetShowing.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Card(imageUrl: self.images[index], index: index, useWebImage: self.$useWebImage)
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$isSheetShowing) {
                    DestinationView(imageUrl: self.images[self.selectedIndex], index: self.selectedIndex, useWebImage: self.$useWebImage)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Images")
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct Card: View {

    let imageUrl: String
    let index: Int
    @Binding var useWebImage: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if useWebImage {
                WebImage(url: URL(string: imageUrl))
                    .resizable()
                    .indicator(.activity)
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5))
                    .transition(.fade)
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 250, maxHeight: 250, alignment: .center)
                    .cornerRadius(12)
                    .clipped()
            } else {
                Image("image\(index)")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 250, maxHeight: 250, alignment: .center)
                    .cornerRadius(12)
                    .clipped()
            }

            HStack {
                Text("Image #\(index + 1) (\(useWebImage ? "WebImage" : "SwiftUI Image"))")
                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                    .bold()
                    .kerning(0.5)

                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .padding(2)
        .border(Color(.systemRed), width: 2)
    }
}
```

Do you have an idea how to fix this issue? 
I already tried to use .resizable(resizingMode: .tile) but I need to shrink the image before I could use just a tile.

For detailed information you can also find the project on GitHub [GitHub Project](https://github.com/stefangerard/ImageIssue)

I would appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: Have you considered clipping on the outer VStack? The one in the cardview, directly internal to the body? If you have any interest in complex views and SwiftUI setups, heres a good link of advanced tutorials, covers things of about this complexity. There's usually about one new video for complex UI every other day: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEHYNiA7SPcP9TOUh2qAhYnwMR2AM0i40

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `.clipped` affects only drawing, and by-default `Button` has all content clickable not depending what it is.

So if you want make your button clickable only in image area, you have to limit hit testing only to its rect explicitly and disable everything else.

Here is a demo of possible approach. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4.

[image]

Demo code (simplified variant of your snapshot):

```swift
struct ButtonCard: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("sea")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 250, maxHeight: 250, alignment: .center)
                .cornerRadius(12)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())    // << define clickable rect !!
                .clipped()

            HStack {
                Text("Image #1")
                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                    .bold()
                    .kerning(0.5)

                Spacer()
            }.allowsHitTesting(false)         // << disable label area !!
        }
        .padding(2)
        .border(Color(.systemRed), width: 2)
    }
}

struct TestClippedButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { print(">> tapped") }) {
            ButtonCard()
        }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
    }
}
```